# handleChange = (e) => {} and handleButtonClick = () => | why there is 'e' has to be inside of () while some do not need letters?

Tags: reactjs

```
handleChagne = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        password: e.target.value
    });
}

handleButtonClick = () => {
    this.setState({
        clicked: true,
        validated: this.state.password === '0000'
    })
}
```

As I can see here, for handleChange there is 'e' inside as well as e.target.value

But, why there is no such letter inside of () in handleButtonClikck statement?

Comment: You don't need to use `e` in handleButtonClick. In this case, you don't have to define that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of arguments a function takes (zero, 1 or five or ten), the exact type of each argument (string, object or boolean and so forth) and the type of the return value of the function (if any) are sometimes called 'function's signature'.

JavaScript allows you to call a function disregarding its signature. That means if the function you are calling takes one or more arguments which are not used inside the function body, then you can skip those arguments e.g. do not supply it all.